# Join 2 SQL Queries

Tags: sql-server

This one should be simple for you experts.  I am trying to join two queries.  One query is named PSB and the other Query is named SSC.  I need to join them on Order_Number.  Table PSB will have one to many rows of data for each order number in the SSC query.  I need to see all of the results in PSB and the matching data from SSC.  I wanted to do an outer join but the error is telling me I have an invalid object name (PSB).

```
Select P1.[Tracking_Number]
  ,P1.[Order_Number]
  ,P1.[Shipped_Warehouse_Name]
  ,P1.[Billed_Weight]
  ,P1.[Package_Quantity]
  ,P1.[Total_Cost_Dollars]
  ,S1.[Order_Number]
  ,S1.[Order_Datetime]
  ,S1.[Ship_City_Name]
  ,S1.[Ship_State_Name]
  ,S1.[Ship_State_Code]
  ,S1.[Zip5]
  ,S1.[Ship_Country_Code]
  ,S1.[Ship_Country_Name]

  From PSB as P1
  Left Outer Join SSC as S1
  on P1.[Order_Number] = S1.[Order_Number]
```

Comment: Is PSB a table in the database and schema you're working in?  Do you have access to it?

Comment: Try `select * from PSB` to see if you have access to it.

Comment: PSB is the query that I have open, for some reason it isn't reading it.  I am very new to SQL and trying to figure it out on my own.  Do I have to save the query I created into some directory for it to be able to read?

Comment: Well I figured it out.  I didn't quite understand the relationship between queries and how they store them.  I created two temp tables and stored the results and then referenced those tables to join them and it was successful.